# Get list of recent OneNote sections and pages

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm using the `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/onenote/notebooks/getRecentNotebooks` endpoint to retrieve a list of the user's recent notebooks. I now want to get sections and pages for those notebooks.

`getRecentNotebooks` returns `displayName` and URLs (like `oneNoteWebUrl`) for each notebook, but I need an ID to use `onenote/notebooks/{id}/sections`. Is there a way to either:

- get a list of recent sections/pages (or sections/pages of recent notebooks) directly; or
- get the ID of a notebook by URL using another endpoint (in graph, I saw that there might be something in the OneNote API, but would prefer not to use that)?

Answer (score 1):

The [/me/onenote/notebooks/GetNotebookFromWebUrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/notebook-getnotebookfromweburl?view=graph-rest-1.0) endpoint can take care of this.